# IntellJ | Exception in plugIn GitHub Copilot (1.1.20.1417)

Tags: intellij-idea, github-copilot

After updating my copilot plugin in IntelliJ I tried to log in where I am redirected to a webpage, I enter my information, click authorize and the page congratulates me with being all set. However, when I return to the IDE I am shown a pop up with the following error message:

"The login to GitHub failed. Please try again"

In the bottom right of the application window I get an indicator of IDE internal error (IDE fatal error):

```
JsonRpcErrorException(requestId=4, code=1001, extraData=null)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.rpc.JsonRPC.parseResponse(JsonRPC.java:52)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.vscodeRpc.DefaultJsonRpcMessageHandler.handleJsonMessage(DefaultJsonRpcMessageHandler.java:74)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.vscodeRpc.VSCodeJsonRpcParser.processPendingContent(VSCodeJsonRpcParser.java:91)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.vscodeRpc.VSCodeJsonRpcParser.appendLocked(VSCodeJsonRpcParser.java:71)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.vscodeRpc.VSCodeJsonRpcParser.append(VSCodeJsonRpcParser.java:39)
    at com.github.copilot.lang.agent.vscodeRpc.AgentProcessHandler$1.onTextAvailable(AgentProcessHandler.java:35)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor141.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:221)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$SimpleOutputReader.onTextAvailable(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:156)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.processInput(BaseOutputReader.java:198)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.readAvailableBlocking(BaseOutputReader.java:136)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.readAvailable(BaseDataReader.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.doRun(BaseDataReader.java:166)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.lambda$start$0(BaseDataReader.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Things I have tried with no results:

- removing the copilot plugin from IntelliJ, downloading an earlier version of the plugin, and importing it from disk to IntelliJ but I still get the same issue
- updating IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bug in co-pilot.
See their bug tracker: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/16230

Answer (score 0):

*Following the link by @Konstantin Annikov*

TL;DR
Downgrading Copilot to [1.1.16.1219](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17718-github-copilot/versions/stable/167546)
worked for me on Intel MacBook 2018